# How to Display multiple videos from JSON using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

I want to display videos on HTML using J Query, all videos should have same height and width and i cannot use for loop for this and I have data set like this

```
function appendReturnedVideos(data) {
    var $html = $();

    $.each(data.videos, function(index, element) {
        $html = $html.add($("<video/>", {
            height: 400,
            //width: 200, // uncomment this if you need to set width as well
            css: {
                'max-width': 400
            },
            src: element
        }));
        $("#images").append($html);    
    });
}

appendReturnedVideos({
    "videos": [
        "https:\/\/outpan-images.s3.amazonaws.com\/lo0e22j0nj-0078915030900.mp4",
        "https:\/\/outpan-images.s3.amazonaws.com\/nkvaonl839-0078915030900.mp4",
        "https:\/\/outpan-images.s3.amazonaws.com\/pjkhqlbgwl-0078915030900.mp4"
    ]
});
```

HTML Part:

```
<div id="videos"></div>
```

Comment: What error do you get in the browser console? You're appending your html to #images but the id in your markup is #videos.

Comment: @AWolf, I have corrected that but i am still facing the same problem.
This is the dynamic video src created 
<video src="https://outpan-images.s3.amazonaws.com/lo0e22j0nj-0078915030900.mp4" style="height: 400px; max-width: 400px;"></video>
but its blank .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The videos were not blank! It's just that they were not being played and hence, displayed as blank (since there was no [poster](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_poster.asp) set). Had you set `controls: true`, you'd have at least had the play button and other controls to interact with the video. Take a look at the below demo and adapt the code to suit your needs.

```js
function appendReturnedVideos(data) {
    var $html = $();

    $.each(data.videos, function(index, element) {
        $html = $html.add($("<video/>", {
            height: 360,
            css: { 'max-width': 480 },
            src: element,
            controls: true,
            autoplay: true, // comment if you don't want video being auto played
            preload: 'auto' // comment if you don't want to preload the videos
        }));
    });
    $("#videos").append($html);
}

appendReturnedVideos({
    "videos": [
        "https:\/\/outpan-images.s3.amazonaws.com\/lo0e22j0nj-0078915030900.mp4",
        "https:\/\/outpan-images.s3.amazonaws.com\/nkvaonl839-0078915030900.mp4",
        "https:\/\/outpan-images.s3.amazonaws.com\/pjkhqlbgwl-0078915030900.mp4"
    ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="videos"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this.

```js
var videos=[

    "https:\/\/outpan-images.s3.amazonaws.com\/lo0e22j0nj-0078915030900.mp4",

    "https:\/\/outpan-images.s3.amazonaws.com\/nkvaonl839-0078915030900.mp4",

    "https:\/\/outpan-images.s3.amazonaws.com\/pjkhqlbgwl-0078915030900.mp4"

];

var items="";
for(var i=0;i<=videos.length;i++){
  items+="<video src="+videos[i]+" style='max-width:400' />";
  }
$("#videos").append(items);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="videos"> </div>
```

Comment: i cannot use for loop and can you give me the solution that is more suitable with my given code.